# PHP - Check if there is a word before AND behind a comma?

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I want a user to enter his city and country seperated with a comma to store the data in my database.

Now my current code is:

```
if (empty($_POST['location']) || substr_count($_POST['location'], ',') != 1)
```

but this only checks if ONE comma is given. I want to check if there is ONE comma AND one word before AND behind the comma. 
Also these words should at least have 2 chars, because I guess there isn't a country or city with one char(?).

Edit: I just found out there are cities with just one character. So please forget my last sentence.

Comment: I think that's a case for RegEx

Comment: it's much easier for us to understand what you're trying to match when you provide an example value, like `city,country -> ok, city,country, -> bad, ...`

Comment: @ZathrusWriter A correct format would be: `city, country` That's why only 1 comma should be allowed and a string before AND behind that comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. `preg_match` with `/,\s*\w{2,}/` will tell you this:

```
if (preg_match('/,\s*\w{2,}/', $_POST['location'])) {
    //Yep - there's a comma followed by at least two characters in there!
}
```

**Autopsy:**

- `,` - a literal `,` character
- `\s*` - space/tab/newline characters repeated 0 to unlimited times
- `\w{2,}` - any letter repeated 2 to unlimited times

---

It seems that you're also checking for empty ones.

```
<?php
    $invalid = false;
    $split = preg_split('/,\s*/', $_POST['location']);
    foreach ($split as $part) {
        if (strlen($part) < 2) {
            $invalid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$invalid) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error!';
    }
?>
```

---

If you require a single regex to do the job for you, you can do this:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\w{2,},\s*)*(\w{2,})$/', $_POST['location'])) {
    echo 'Success!';
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/qE6bX1)

```
OK    city,country   
ERROR ok, city,country,   
ERROR n, foo, bar   
ERROR foo, bar, n   
ERROR ,foo, bar, test   
OK    foo,bar   
OK    foobar
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm checking for empty ones"? If you're asking about my code, it should check what is NOT allowed to type in like entering nothing at all.

Comment: @Vay My regex would allow `foo, bar, foobar,` as `, bar` and `, foobar` matches it, even though it ends in a comma. The `explode` solution would not.

Comment: I just found out that there are one-character-cities in the world, so I'd update the 2 to a 1

Comment: @Vay I've added a new regex that does the job without `explode` if you'd prefer. Here you can also just change `{2,}` to `+` to symbolize "repeated one or more times". `/^(\w+,\s*)*(\w+)$/`

Comment: Thank you, but why is only one word also allowed?

Comment: It also seems that `a, b, c` is allowed with your third code example.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, because I haven't used RegEx before. I can't get it to work the way that I want. What I exactly want is this: 1) One character or more at the beginning in [a-zA-Z] format. 2) Only 1 single comma allowed in the whole input field after the first character(s). 3) One character or more after that comma in [a-zA-Z] format. 4) No special characters, comma or anything like that after this character. 5) No empty inputs allowed. 6) Not only one word or char allowed without a comma. 7) Only this format: `city,country` (irrelevant if user puts a space after comma or not)

Comment: @Vay Ah I see - if you want country to be required use this: `/^([a-zA-Z]+),\s*([a-zA-Z]+)$/`, or if it should be optional: `/^([a-zA-Z]+)(?:,\s*([a-zA-Z]+))?$/`

Comment: Hey, thank you. Meanwhile I just came up with this code: `if (empty($_POST['location']) 
  || 
  !preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]{1,}\s*,\s*)*([a-zA-Z]{1,})$/', $_POST['location']) 
  || 
  substr_count($_POST['location'], ',') != 1)`. It was perfect until I forgot and realized that I HAVE TO allow special characters for french city names for example. I tried [^0-9*]+ but then pretty much everything is allowed. Don't want to bother you, but can you help me with this? Then it should be finished.

Comment: `[^0-9*]+` means "any character that is not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 or `*` repeated 1 or more times", so it would **not** match any number. Remember that `{1,}` is the same as `+`. Your regex will match the first unlimited times (`*` means "repeated 0 or more times). `/^(\pL+)\s*,\s*(\pL+)$/` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried this and also added to allow whitespaces before the city and the country (because I trim them anyway, before putting in into the database), but it doesn't recognize words with special chars like the cities I've tested: http://regex101.com/r/eW9gQ3

Comment: @Vay Sorry about that. Add `u` as a modifier:  [`/^\s*(\pL+)\s*,\s*(\pL+)\s*$/u`](http://regex101.com/r/uS3nL0) for unicode.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Hey, just found another thing I haven't thought of. There are city names having some spaces like: `Frankfurt am Main, Germany`. What do I have to change to allow this?

Comment: @Vay If you switch out `\pL+` with `[\pL ]+` that also allowes spaces.

Comment: Does `\pL` also include support for Korean, Japanese, etc? I want to create a location-database. Everytime a user types in a city and country, it will be stored in a database. And then confirmed by admins. And this is about a worldwide social community. So I don't know about other countries and city names, but I just found out that it's impossible to validate prenames and surnames. Is this similiar with cities?

Comment: @Vay "\pL - Any kind of letter from any language.", so yes - it should work with korean, japanese, russian, czech etc.. You *can* validate citities through some of the open databases with city-names. [Here's the first result for "country city database" on google](http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities).

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend

```
if(empty($_POST['location']) || !preg_match('/.+, .+/', $_POST['location'])
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, because I haven't used RegEx before. I can't get it to work the way that I want. What I exactly want is this: 1) One character or more at the beginning in [a-zA-Z] format. 2) Only 1 single comma allowed in the whole input field after the first character(s). 3) One character or more after that comma in [a-zA-Z] format. 4) No special characters, comma or anything like that after this character. 5) No empty inputs allowed. 6) Not only one word or char allowed without a comma. 7) Only this format: city,country (irrelevant if user puts a space after comma or not)

Answer (score -1):

do this:

```
if(preg_match('/^.[a-zA-Z]+.( )?,.( )?.[a-zA-Z]+$/i', $_POST['location']))
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, because I haven't used RegEx before. I can't get it to work the way that I want. What I exactly want is this: 1) One character or more at the beginning in [a-zA-Z] format. 2) Only 1 single comma allowed in the whole input field after the first character(s). 3) One character or more after that comma in [a-zA-Z] format. 4) No special characters, comma or anything like that after this character. 5) No empty inputs allowed. 6) Not only one word or char allowed without a comma. 7) Only this format: city,country (irrelevant if user puts a space after comma or not)

Comment: ok, try my new regular expression, that one should work perfectly for your situation; notice the ^$ characters around the regex tells it to compare from beginning to end